# Is it possible to navigate the graph of an Animator Controller?

Tags: unity-game-engine

Is it possible to navigate the graph represented by an Animator Controller in Unity by code at runtime?

**Setup**
For example, if I have two states "Idle" and "Clicked". In order to transition from "Idle" to "Clicked" state, I have to issue a SetTrigger("Clicked") call on the animator, which then starts playing the "SwiperItemClicked" animation clip.

[image]

**Now to the question**
When I know the name of the trigger ("Clicked"), how can I find out programmatically, what animation clip will be played after I reach state "Clicked"? I need to know the name of the animation clip on the "Clicked" state (in this example "SwiperItemClicked").

I am using Unity 2018.3.0f2.

Comment: Added a comment to the question to mention that I want to do this during runtime.

Answer (score 1):

Only available with editor script

```csharp
public static string FindClipName(AnimatorController controller, string triggerName)
{
    foreach (var layer in controller.layers)
        foreach (var state in layer.stateMachine.states)
            foreach (var transition in state.state.transitions)
                foreach (var condition in transition.conditions)
                    if (condition.parameter == triggerName)
                        return transition.destinationState.motion.name;
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Thanks! "Editor script" means it does not work during runtime, I guess.

Comment: I think it's impossible in runtime, there is no condition class exported under latest Unity API.

Answer (score 0):

Vectors have no right angles graphs. I believe it is not possible to navigate the graph of an animator controller. Only parallel and angle lines are accepted in an animated controller.